# How can I use registers with Elisp?

Tags: copy-paste, registers

It appears that all the documentation about registers revolves around C-x r [action] [char] or M-x [command] RET [char].

But let's say I want to create my own command using the register, how do I go about it?
For example, let's say I want to create a second clipboard using M-c and M-v to copy and paste respectively.

Naively, I tried

```lisp
    (defun mycopy()
      (interactive)
      (copy-to-register "w"))
```

which of course doesn't work. I tried other variations on this command and a few other commands to no avail.

So, if I understand, registers are not meant to be used through elisp?

Perhaps I can mimic a key press with elisp code? Or should I forgo registers entirely for that purpose and simply create my own global variable to store information to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you didn't consult the doc (using `C-h f`) of `copy-to-register`.  You didn't pass it a register, which needs to be a **character**, not a string.  And you didn't pass it the region boundaries, so it has no way of knowing what text you want to copy.

This should do what you want:

```lisp
(defun mycopy (begin end)
  "..."
  (interactive "r")
  (copy-to-register ?w begin end))

(defun mypaste (&optional arg)
  "..."
  (interactive "P")
  (insert-register ?w (not arg)))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-c") 'mycopy)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-v") 'mypaste)
```

This is what `C-h f copy-to-register` says:

> `copy-to-register` is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
> `register.el`.
>
> It is bound to `C-M-S-backspace`, `C-x r x`, `C-x r s`.
>
> (copy-to-register REGISTER START END &optional DELETE-FLAG REGION)
>
> Copy region into register `REGISTER`.
>
> With prefix arg, delete as well.
>
> Called from program, takes five args: `REGISTER`, `START`, `END`, `DELETE-FLAG`,
> and `REGION`.
>
> - `START` and `END` are buffer positions indicating what to copy.
> - The optional argument `REGION` if non-nil, indicates that we're not just
>   copying some text between `START` and `END`, but we're copying the region.
>
> Interactively, reads the register using `register-read-with-preview`.

More generally, you can use `set-register`? `C-h f` says:

> `set-register` is a compiled Lisp function in `register.el`.
>
> `(set-register REGISTER VALUE)`
>
> Set contents of Emacs register named `REGISTER` to `VALUE`.  Returns `VALUE`.
> See the documentation of the variable `register-alist` for possible `VALUE`s.

Other than that, consult library `register.el` for how to create and access registers using Elisp.

Comment: The Emacs manual has a whole chapter on registers: `(info "(emacs)Registers")` or `C-h i g(emacs)registers`.

Comment: Thank you! I think I did look at the doc with C-h f but it meant nothing to me (and therefore, dismissed it too quickly). However, your answer prompted me to look at the doc for the interactive function and I looked up elisp character literals. In hindsight, it all makes sense. I am new to emacs but the bigger picture is building itself slowly but surely.

Comment: @NickD Yes. That is what I had looked at before (but on gnu.org instead). While it explains the bindings, it doesn't say anything about elisp.

Comment: That is true: you might want to look through the "intro to elisp" book: `(info "(eintr)")` or `C-h i g(eintr)` or on the web [An Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/eintr.html).